# Spurious DuplicateKeyException from Linq-to-SQL SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, duplicates

I am moving rows from one database to another using Linq-to-SQL like this:-

```
remote_rows = (from a in remotedb.MyRTable
                   where a.Key1 >= some_value &&
                         a.Key2 >= some_other_value
                   select a).ToList();

local_rows = (from a in localdb.MyLTable
                  where a.Key1 >= some_value &&
                        a.Key2 >= some_other_value
                  select a).ToList();

new_rows = remote_rows.ConvertAll(new Converter<MyRTable, MyLTable>(MyRToMyL));
new_rows.RemoveAll(rrow => local_rows.Exists(lrow => rrow.Key1 == lrow.Key1 &&
                                                     rrow.Key2 == lrow.Key2));

if (new_rows.Count() > 0)
{
    localdb.MyLTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(new_rows);
    localdb.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This code is invoked at intervals in a loop, and it works fine until some other process deletes rows out of localdb.MyLTable (in the current case, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to do this). It attempts to recreate these rows (which is intended behaviour), but the result is always a `DuplicateKeyException`.

I have checked the contents of the `new_rows` and `localdb.MyLTable` objects and determined that there are no duplicates, and also I changed the primary key of MyLTable to an autoincrement value, which showed that duplicates are not being created.

It appears that the `localdb` object is retaining the rows that were deleted by the other process, although they are not displayed when I listed all the rows in it.

I can correct the problem by disconnecting and reconnecting to the database between invokations of the code, but that doesn't seem right to me.

What is the recommended way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datacontext grows stale. It is supposed to be short-lived.

You should recreate the datacontext each time you start this proces and dispose after it rightwaway.